# $e^+e^- \to p^+p^-$ cross-section?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics

Does anyone know of a calculated or measured cross-section somewhere for $e^+e^-$ annihilation into a proton-antiproton pair, say at the LEP? Seems to me that it would be rather strongly energetically suppressed relative to various lighter meson pairs production at least, and possibly by some selection rule I haven't thought of, which might explain the lack of info and interest.

Comment: Just visit https://www.hepdata.net/

Comment: Thanks!  Hadn't heard of that site before.